# Cannot add in-app product to released app

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console

I'm testing in-app purchase. I release my app as beta test to play console. In play console -> Store presence -> In-app products, play console show me the following information, 
[image]

I already added permission to my android manifest file as follow,

```
<permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload the apk after adding the permission and .aidl file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added your permission, uploaded the APK, and re-released the app then it should work. If it doesn't then it is a bug and you should contact Play console support using the help menu (behind the question mark icon).

If you want to check your APK yourself you can.

On the APK which is currently published do

```
aapt dump badging my.apk
```

If the permission is printed then you have added it correctly.